# Random Space - Messed up Alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my first website and I'm very pleased with my progress thus far, but I've run into an issue.

I'm trying to align a black "block" with the blue block above it. For some reason, there is like a random space right infront of the black bar.

I am using the 960 grid system (16 column variant). Here is an image of the issue I am having: http://gyazo.com/4a9a0ba8b31105f1e95029f9cf878009.png

Here is the code I have. Can anyone understand why I have that random space infront of it?

```
<div id="banner" class="grid_16">
    <div id="socialmedia" class="grid_3 prefix_7">
        <img src="images/facebook.gif" alt="facebook icon">
        <img src="images/twitter.gif" alt="twitter icon">
        <img src="images/youtube.gif" alt="youtube icon">               
    </div>
    <div id="bar" class="grid_16">
    </div>          
</div>
```

And then the CSS:

```
#bar {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the left margin from `#bar`?

Comment: I don't have a left-margin on the bar (as far I know)

Comment: I just tried setting the left margin to 0 and it worked. Disregard please! I would still like to know why I had to do that though..

Comment: Try reproducing it in a closed environment like http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Something else is adding a margin in your CSS. It could be a statement that targets `#bar`, or one that targets all children of a parent container, or even a general statement that targets all divs (but is overridden in the case of the blue box).

Comment: I am Chrome fan but for this you can use Firefox and open your page with firefox embeded 3D tool to see layers on page. Then you should be able to see what is on the left side.